# Having a cors error on streaming pdf on laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, cors, pdf-generation

I am trying to stream the pdf from using laravel api, showing to node.js dashboard. But I'm receiving a CORS error

I'm using this pdf package: [Niklas Laravel PDF](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf?tab=readme-ov-file)

Error Message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘{{staging}}/get_order_invoice?order_id=1’ from origin ‘http://localhost:3000/’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource.

cors.php

```
<?php
return [
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,];
```

On Laravel api:

```
public function getUserOrderInvoiceAdmin(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'order_id' => 'required|integer|exists:orders,id',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Required fields are missing',
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ], 400);
    }

    $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    $order = Orders::where('id', $request->order_id)
        ->with([
            'shop',
            'orderItems' => function ($query) {
                $query->with([
                    'product' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with(['images', 'category']);
                    }
                ]);
            },
            'user',
            'orderDeliveryStatus',
            'userAddress'
        ])
        ->first();

    $data = [
        'order' => $order,
        'user' => $order->user,
        'shop' => $order->shop,
        'orderItems' => $order->orderItems,
        'orderDeliveryStatus' => $order->orderDeliveryStatus,
        'userAddress' => $order->userAddress,
    ];
    $dateTime = now();
    $fileName = $dateTime->format('Ymd') . '_invoice.pdf';
    $pdf = FacadesPdf::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
    $pdf->save(storage_path('app/public/' . $fileName));
    $urlToDownload =  Storage::disk('public')->url($fileName);
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'url' => $urlToDownload,
    ]);
    if ($request->type == 1) {
    } else if ($request->type == 2) {
        return $pdf->stream($fileName);
    } else if ($request->type == 3) {
        $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
    } else if ($request->type == 4) {
        Storage::put('public/pdf/invoice.pdf', $pdf->output());
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    } else {
        return "please send help :)";
    }
}
```

Comment: "niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf is not maintained! This repository has been deprecated and archived on 2023-08-22. Look at https://github.com/misterspelik/laravel-pdf for a potential alternative."